# How can I generate List<String> from nested objects?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2005, nested-class

I have the following nested classes:

```
class Report
{
    List<ReportItem> list;
}

class ReportItem
{
    public string str1;
    public string str2;
}
```

Without adding any new methods to the the above classes, if I have `Report r`, how can I generate a `List<String>` of all the `str1` strings conatined in `r.list`?

No Linq as I am using VS2005.

Comment: These are not nested objects.

Comment: @Kobi: A nested object is simply an object inside another object.

Comment: @CuongLe: see my answer below

Comment: In C#, the default access modifier for class fields is `private`. So you can't access any of the fields above without modifying the classes.

Comment: @Eren: accepted, but it's not really a critical issue in the question. Why not just edit it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on .NET version, you could use `Array.ConvertAll` function to translate elements, like this:

```
new List<string>(Array.ConvertAll(list.ToArray(), delegate(Report item){ return item.str1; }));
```

Kind of messy way though.

Comment: @Kobi: What is the `=>` operator?  I can't find it in the help pages.

Comment: @Gray - That is similar to a `delegate`, but that is overly complex - your solution of using a `foreach` is much simpler.

Comment: Note that both `list` and `str1` are private fields, so this won't work (unless the question is wrong and they are really supposed to be public).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
foreach (ReportItem ri in r.list) { resultList.Add(ri.str1); }
```